# WordPress theme showing nothing when doing live preview

Tags: wordpress, wamp

I'm using Wamp Server to make my Word press website so I added themes to it but when I did a live preview of the theme it shows this

[image]

Plz, tell me what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: the database does not contain any posts or data of that theme, thus, it is showing nothing.

Comment: But i have created the database also and when i was using it previously it worked fine but now it is not working...Also it was showing Hello world But now that is also gone

Comment: i am not saying that you do or do not have a database, make sure there are data in the database first

Comment: You are right there is no data in database but it should not affect the apperance of the theme

Comment: if you do not have data to display that every block of page will not show. try to insert some data and see for yourself

Comment: Ok i will try that Thanks For the help by the way...

Comment: There is no posts on your site.. Default hello world post may be you were  deleted. Add some posts and try..

Comment: Ya i think i deleted Hello world by mistake but now i don't know how to add it I'm new to wordpress

Comment: Ok now i added hello world and it shows hello world back but i cant see the preview of the website...

Comment: How to solve it now...